# Where is realisation of ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.wav

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new in ffmpeg. I want use ffmpeg in my program. I can not find realisation of this comand `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.wav`  in library

Comment: Show the complete log from the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: I do not need this in comand line. I want use source code of this comand in my program.

Comment: That is probably about 200 lines of C code. You can get a tutorial here https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial#learn-ffmpeg-libav-the-hard-way

Comment: Yes i read this. But I looking for ready code that is in ffmeg librery. I can write my own but, I want use optimized code

Answer (score 0):

as I understand it, no one knows the answer. Then I will make the implementation myself. Read the questions carefully before you write comments and put nuts